# paper js export and import json issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, paperjs

I tried to export to json my project and then reimport it, The issue is that Objects reimported aren't mutable, how can I fix it? This is an example, thanks.
[Link](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bZI9b4MwEIb/yokFkKJ8SVmoujSVKnVoq6Rb6eDAERzMOTo7SVXEf68NoUnUMtl+P/z4RBOQqDFIgnWFNiuDUZDp3O+PgiGTrBDugfAEb8KW46XkTGHUpATuy5AsctLLWpKNZovpCBbTeNQbWOTyYBKYL1Jq47uUUuoqx4VUaqmVZlce5oKrJ0akcJBzYYVXjK7x0a1Dn/RAjJkVtL2FWg2H0QXEc8ymDuQKbt4dOjpP8tv0l+VBHTC8dpxxGiO/MQHfUqMxYus2HSJoWyKDt4VtD7ozmlxkz3rnasb4tddsn9evL1ETCrO2LGkbJoVQBttbHMZaHzGKU5pMwA3blbn2oQk2WGhGkLUvTGm4oDOeQ7DCXga98aKB6CRteRlefMn1xg7MI3cF7ywxB6shR4UWuxyQtnDSXDnu/2jdE9yvs2EU1d4P2wTJx2f7Aw==)!

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your case is that variable `rectangle` points to the initial, removed rectangle.

When you reimport your project, a new variable is created, representing the newly rendered rectangle.

A handy way to access would be the following:

(1) Before exporting the project into JSON, give this rectangle a name:

```
rectangle.name = 'theRectangle';
```

(2) After re-import you can access it and remove this way:

```
project.activeLayer.children.theRectangle.remove();
```

See the updated sketch [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jZLBbtswDIZfhfDFNpC6SYFcHPTSFihQDNvQHOcdGJuO1chSQClpuyDvPkpuEhe91CdLP/nzI6lDYrCnpEyWG/J1l0yS2jbhvEeGWrEmuAVDr/AbfVfcK641ZYfKgHw1GU9cDrJVxmez+XQC82k+GQIYG7VzJdzMK3PMF5WpTLQsWqX1vdWWxTxtkDePTGTSk9ygx6A429OD/KchMwAx1R7N+jPU8+kyu4AEjtlUQEZwN/FS6ALJ2ekry53eUTqO+MA5OPWPSgguPTmHazlERLC+I4YQlh4rc30N2DSAECYL3o6ox65RlZKSe+4gXQx9vjhrRNuyfRGpoLetZf+0/PUzO6Tolp6VWadli9rR8XM3TL3dU5ZHDNmVmEmBkxOsqLVMoPpgWJlTgRj4kQTPNMhgV0F0kL0q3126yC95Q2AEC8h52JNY+E45KSlDdxAh4eoqYkhvCleaHKBQNKptieURyd6tcVbwtV1noyXfXmaAtVd7+oHvxEXdKd1IYjGe3fC+vh1+ntRC3vyKCTfb8EpcUv75e/wP).

Comment: I am not able to use this project as its value is always null for me. How can I access / import / get the current project? Thank you.